# Sending a byte[] over a stream effeciently

Tags: java, sockets, buffer, inputstream, outputstream

I'm trying to send a `byte[]` over a stream (from a socket).

I've tried using an ObjectOutput/InputStream to send and receive the `byte[]` but its too slow. Even with setting the `noTcpDelay(true)` and increasing the sending and receiving buffer sizes in the socket.

What is the most efficient way of sending the byte[] over the network and how would I go about it?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `ByteArrayInputStream` and `ByteArrayOutputStream`? I find them the most suitable Streams to read/write `byte[]`